# Selecing DATA attribute with cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

how would i go about selecting the **data-preconnect-urls** value from this html?

```
<a class="V0MxL r-iouRA4dnjnsk" href="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=DChcSEwjajYGGnerhAhVtANMKHS7gDKYYABAAGgJ3Yg&amp;ohost=www.google.com&amp;cid=CAESEeD2qv-1juqYmFBdcohZcFwG&amp;sig=AOD64_3EPN3EpYMWlKpKa-PyxGDbSTEInw&amp;q=&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjl6_mFnerhAhWy1eAKHacmB80Q0Qx6BAgLEAE&amp;adurl=" id="vn1s0p1c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="https://www.expedia.com/" jsl="$t t-r1glFWqNI5A;$x 0;"><h3 class="sA5rQ">Expedia - Book Cheap Flights | Fly At Incredible Prices | expedia.com‎</h3><br><div class="ads-visurl"><span class="Z98Wse">Ad</span><cite class="UdQCqe">www.expedia.com/Flights/Book</cite>‎</div></a>
```

Comment: `$('a').data('preconnectUrls')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#data-name-value-),

```
$('a').data('preconnect-urls')
```

Comment: Always add explanations to your answers to explain to the OP and others what you are solving